# How to disable dialog "Save your Copy" for "InPersonSigner" recipients?

Tags: c#-4.0, docusignapi

How to disable dialog "Save your Copy" for "InPersonSigner" recipients or make changes in it ?
We need this because we decided to suppress emails to Embedded Signers and send email encrypted from our system.
Or, is it possible to add password to documents that send with mail to recipients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given in the DocuSign docs on pg 41 [Signer Save a Copy](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-signing-resource-file-information.pdf#page=41)